# How to enhance combination code with a time variable

Tags: powerbi, combinations, market-basket-analysis

I found the following code by v-shex-msft I would like to use to come up with a list of combinations. [Kudos to him](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Sum-customers-by-product-combination-buyed-a-b-a-c-b-c-or-a-b-c/td-p/89362). Now I would like to add a time variable so that only events are combined that occurred within 24 hours. Unfortunately, the filter function won't allow me to use more arguments:

Original Code:

```
Summary Table =

var temp= 
SUMMARIZE(
    Sheet5,
    Sheet5[Customer],
    "Combinations",CONCATENATEX(
        FILTER(
            SUMMARIZE(
                Sheet5,
                [Customer],
                Sheet5[Type]
            ),
            Sheet5[Customer] = EARLIER(Sheet5[Customer])
        ),
        [Type]&","
    )
)

return
SUMMARIZE(
    temp,
    [combinations],
    "Number",COUNTAX(
        FILTER(
            temp,
            [combinations]=EARLIER([combinations])
        ),
        [Customer]
    )
)
```

I tried to add the time variable as follows:

```
 Summary Table =

var temp = 
SUMMARIZE(
    Sheet5,
    Sheet5[Customer],
    "Combinations",CONCATENATEX(
        FILTER(
            SUMMARIZE(
                Sheet5,
                [Customer],
                Sheet5[Type], 
                Sheets5[time]
            ),
            Sheet5[Customer] = EARLIER(Sheet5[Customer]) 
            && Sheets5[time]+1 >= Earlier(Sheets5[time]) 
            && Sheets5[time]-1 <= Earlier(Sheets5[time])
        ),
        [Type]&","
    )
)

return
SUMMARIZE(
    temp,
    [combinations],
    "Number",COUNTAX(
        FILTER(
            temp,
            [combinations] = EARLIER([combinations])
        ),
        [Customer]
    )
)
```

Any Ideas on what is going wrong? Thank you your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "Unfortunately the filter function wont allow me to use more arguments"? Are you getting any error? If yes, please show the error message with your question.

Comment: Hi @mkRabbani good advice, the error message is as follows: A single value for the 'time' column cannot be determined in the 'sheet5' table. This can happen when a measure formula references a column that contains many values ​​without specifying an aggregation such as 'min', 'max', 'count', or 'sum' to get a single result.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this below code-

```
 Summary Table =

var temp = 
SUMMARIZE(
    Sheet5,
    Sheet5[Customer],
    "Combinations",CONCATENATEX(
        FILTER(
            SUMMARIZE(
                Sheet5,
                [Customer],
                Sheet5[Type], 
                Sheets5[time]
            ),
            MAX(Sheet5[Customer]) = EARLIER(Sheet5[Customer]) 
            && MAX(Sheets5[time]) +1 >= Earlier(Sheets5[time]) 
            && MAX(Sheets5[time]) -1 <= Earlier(Sheets5[time])
        ),
        [Type]&","
    )
)

return
SUMMARIZE(
    temp,
    [combinations],
    "Number",COUNTAX(
        FILTER(
            temp,
            [combinations] = EARLIER([combinations])
        ),
        [Customer]
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. Now it doesnt complain about the time set within the max function, but it still complains about the time within the earlier function. It shows me the same error message. I tried to set a max function within the Earlier as well but it wont work. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Use MAX around Sheet5[Customer]. Check my updated answer.